# Using ActiveResource to manipulate another application's Database

Tags: activeresource, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-on-rails-3.2, puppet

I've come to seek your collective wisdom.

My goal, an overview:
In order to better manage computers for various clients, I'm attempting to extend Puppet's [Dashboard](http://www.example.com/). It's a Rails 2 application, and I'm trying to extend it with a Rails 3 application I'm writing. There are a few problems that make Dashboard less than perfect for my needs, but the solutions are simple. I'm going to focus on one, because I feel that the answer to this question will help me figure the rest out. I've been looking into solutions that don't alter the dashboard code at all, because I'm not the maintainer, and don't want to make a future mess.

I thought a lot about how to do this best. I thought about plugging directly into the database but I got cold feet after doing a little googling. It appears that setting up a second database connection isn't that difficult, the thing I don't like is altering another application's database while it's running. Please say something if I'm passing up a perfectly reasonable option, based on superstition.

There were a few other ideas, but the one that I started in on finally, and had marginal success with was accessing Dashboard's database via REST. It's built in, why not use it? Well, I was able to manipulate a couple of the tables, but not the one that I wanted to. So there are three tables to be aware of in this situation.

1. nodes (basically computers)
2. node_groups (the groups you can put computers in)
3. node_group_memberships (the join table that relates 1 and 2 to each other)

I can add and remove both nodes, and node_groups, but I want to be able to create a connection between the two as well. In order to create a new user, I have an ActiveResource model set up that looks like this:

```
class PuppetNode < ActiveResource::Base                                                                                                                                                    
 self.site = "http://127.0.0.1:4000/"                                                          
 self.element_name = "node"                                                                   
 attr_accessor :grouped          
end
```

I'm then free to create new nodes, or grab info from the nodes table via the console. It might look something like this:

```
PuppetNode.create(:column_name => "and so on")
```

The same goes for node_groups, and I can even create a Rails 3 model that doesn't wig out for node_group_memberships, but I can't create anything in that table. I can see if I look at the Rails 2 node_group_membership controller (by the good folks over at Puppet Labs), that there is a create method

```
class NodeGroupMembershipsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :json
  before_filter :raise_if_enable_read_only_mode, :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :standardize_post_data, :only => [:create]

  def create
    create! do |success, failure|
      success.json { render :text => @node_group_membership.to_json, :content_type => 'application/json', :status => 201 }
      failure.json { render :text => {}.to_json, :content_type => 'application/json', :status => 422 }
    end
  end

  # we want: {node_group_membership => {node_id => <id>, node_group_id => <id>}
  # allow and convert: {node_name => <name>, group_name => <name>}
  def standardize_post_data
    unless params[:node_group_membership]
      params[:node_group_membership] = {}
      node  = Node.find_by_name(params[:node_name])
      group = NodeGroup.find_by_name(params[:group_name])
      params[:node_group_membership][:node_id] = (node && node.id)
      params[:node_group_membership][:node_group_id] = (group && group.id)
    end
  end
end
```

But for whatever reason it chokes out every time I try to create an association with something like this

```
irb(main):005:0> PuppetNodeGroupMembership.create(:node_id => 20, :node_group_id => 5) 
=> #<PuppetNodeGroupMembership:0x007fb3150af878 @attributes={"node_id"=>20, "node_group_id"=>5}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=false, @remote_errors=#<ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid: Failed.  Response code = 422.  Response message = .>, @validation_context=nil, @errors=#<ActiveResource::Errors:0x007fb3150af4e0 @base=#<PuppetNodeGroupMembership:0x007fb3150af878 ...>, @messages={}>>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, I've already put a solid 8 miserable hours into trying to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For better or for worse one thing that does work is connecting to a second database with the same Rails application. I'm leaving this marked as "An Answer" for now, but not "The Answer".

This is the resource that I found that helped me along:
http://www.rubynaut.net/articles/2008/05/31/how-to-access-multiple-database-in-rails.html